# Getting Uncaught TypeError: path.split is not a function while using Controller (react-hook-form)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am trying to set value of Textfield (MUI) using prop inside controller, I am getting this error `TypeError: path.split is not a function`.

I searched muiltple questions some have mentioned use `{...register('value_name')}` but I want to use controller and using register again inside controller makes double register.

See the code -

```
const { control, handleSubmit,setValue} = useForm();
useEffect(() => {
setValue({'Short_description': "Subject",'Supplier_Name': "Sender"});
}, []);
```

```
return(
<Controller
    render={({
    field: { value } }) => (
    <TextField  fullWidth value={value} />)}
    name="Supplier_Name"
    control={control}                    
/>
<Controller
    render={({
    field: { value } }) => (
    <TextField fullWidth value={value} />)}
    name="Short_description"
    control={control}
/>
);
```

I also tried using `const { control } = useFormContext();` but then I get `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'control' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is null.`

I cannot find any solutions online so any help is appreciated.
CSB - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-controller-issue-6wco7

Comment: I'm getting the same error doing similar operation but with register. I'm reusing a code I have in a different project already in production so I try to downgrade to react-hook-form 6. It worked on v6 but not v7.
Probably something changed in the new version. Here is the v7 documentation, hopefully it can help you: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/releases/tag/v7.0.0

Comment: Seems they made some changes to register and controller: https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/ Maybe we are on a good track ;)